# Can't get .show() to work on ajax success

Tags: jquery

Below is the code that I am having problems with.  The issue is the 2 specific lines where i am transversing the DOM and attempting to execute .show() on .cell-toolbar a[href$="#edit"] and .cell-toolbar a[href$="#delete"]' respectively.  And as shown below, i have attempted to execute .show in 2 different places, neither with any success.  the console.log in the code below does return the appropriate jQuery object for the selector.  Also worth noting I am on jQuery 1.2

```
$('.bstory-page-preview .cell').droppable({
    scope: 'cells',
    hoverClass: 'cellHover',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        var container   = $(this);
        container.find('.cell-toolbar a[href$="#edit"]').show(); // Does not work
        container.find('.cell-toolbar a[href$="#delete"]').show(); // Does not work
        var toolbar     = container.find('.cell-toolbar').clone();
        container.html(toolbar);

        var nid = getNid($(ui.draggable));
        var did = getDid($(this));
        var region = $(this).attr('data-region');

        $.ajax({
            url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'bstory/page/' + did + '/' + region + '/' + nid + '/save',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {

                container.append(data.node);
                container.find('.cell-toolbar a[href$="#edit"]').show();  // Does not work
                container.find('.cell-toolbar a[href$="#delete"]').show(); // Does not work
                console.log(container.find('.cell-toolbar a[href$="#edit"]'));

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you're trying to access elements before the DOM has drawn them. Try adding a slight delay:

```
                container.append(data.node);
                window.setTimeout(function() {
                   container.find('.cell-toolbar a[href$="#edit"]').show();  // Does not work
                   container.find('.cell-toolbar a[href$="#delete"]').show(); // Does not work
                   console.log(container.find('.cell-toolbar a[href$="#edit"]'));
          },50)
```

Comment: it looks like it was user error.  I had code later in my file that was hiding it after the .show();  :(